# Кросс-компиляция OpenGL приложения из Linux на разные платформы

Tags: c++, opengl, кросс-компиляция

есть код написаный на чистом C++ и OpenGL. Как данный код скомпилировать прямо в Linux для  Windows и macOS. Поскольку у каждой ОС своё название библиотеки, и местонахождение библиотеки в ОС разный, то каким способом это решить, или все же нужно этот код отдельно компилировать в каждой среде?

P.S. Использую GLFW & GLEW. QtOpenGL не самый лучший вариант

Comment: Вопрос ведь не только в ОС, но и в архитектуре процессора.

Comment: Ну в линуксе есть mingw-w64, установите его, он есть в ubuntu. Может быть это то что вам нужно. С помощью этого можно компилировать прям в исполняемые файлы windows. А вот насчёт мака я не знаю.